# hamcrest: how to input Boolean value

Tags: python, hamcrest, pyhamcrest

I am not sure why I see error when I have this code. all_is_valid is highlighted in yellow and when I hover over I see below error message. How do I avoid not highlighting it?

*Expected type 'Matcher[bool]' (matched generic type 'Matcher[T]'), got 'bool' instead*

```
all_is_valid=True  
actual = None
if not actual:
    all_is_valid = False
    assert_that(True, all_is_valid,"test failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to convert your input to bool won't work like that. Python considers any non-empty string True. So doing bool(input()) is basically the same as doing input() != ''. Both return true even if the input wasn't "True". Just compare the input given directly to the strings "True and "False":`isTrue = True
while isTrue:

```
isTrue = bool(int(input("Continue? 1 for yes, 0 for no: ")))`
```

Comment: Not sure how to add in this case? Should I do (bool(int(all_is_valid)))